# How can I get Onedrive to automatically save screenshots to a different folder than "Camera Roll"?

Tags: screenshots, onedrive

Currently, onedrive uploads all photos from different folder on my mobile phone to the same  "Camera Roll" folder, however on windows it saves screenshots to a different folder "Pictures\Screenshots"; That would be very convenient if it was possible to do the same thing on phone.

Answer (score 1):

The OneDrive app doesn't currently support this. It looks like it's already been suggested on UserVoice several times, but [this one](https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/suggestions/11522583-destination-folder-for-photo-uploads) looks to have the most votes, so you can add your support there as well.

Alternatively, you can try third-party apps that support OneDrive accounts, like [FolderSync](https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/suggestions/11522583-destination-folder-for-photo-uploads). In the case of FolderSync you'd need to set it up a little differently, because it doesn't have a "upload pictures" setting to my knowledge. Instead you can set up a one-way sync between your phone's camera folder (or screenshots, or what have you) and a destination folder in your OneDrive account.